Magento 2 Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in .phtml template
I encountered an issue after updating the .phtml template for the Newsletter block in my Magento store. Here's the .phtml file I'm working with:
<?php
use Hyva\Theme\Model\ViewModelRegistry;
use Hyva\Theme\ViewModel\HeroiconsOutline;
use Hyva\Theme\ViewModel\ReCaptcha;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe;

/** @var Subscribe $block */
/** @var Escaper $escaper */
/** @var ViewModelRegistry $viewModels */
/** @var ReCaptcha $recaptcha */
/** @var HeroiconsOutline $heroicons */
$heroicons = $viewModels->require(HeroiconsOutline::class);
$recaptcha = $block->getData('viewModelRecaptcha');
$content = $block->getChildHtml('blog.subscribe.content');
$items = json_decode($content, true);
?>
<div>
    <div class="absolute inset-0">
        <img class="h-full w-full object-cover"
            src="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($items['image']) ?>"
            alt="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($items['image-alt']) ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="relative container">
        <h2>
            <?= htmlspecialchars_decode($items['title']) ?>
        </h2>
        <h3>
            <?= htmlspecialchars_decode($items['subtitle']) ?>
        </h3>
        <h3>
            <?= htmlspecialchars_decode($items['subtitle2']) ?>
        </h3>
        <form aria-label="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Subscribe to Newsletter')) ?>">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input name="email" type="email" required id="blog-newsletter-subscribe"
                        placeholder="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($items['email-placeholder']) ?>"
                        aria-describedby="blog-newsletter-subscribe">
                    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                    <?= $recaptcha ? $recaptcha->getInputHtml(ReCaptcha::RECAPTCHA_FORM_ID_NEWSLETTER) : '' ?>
                    <button class="btn-secondary h-10 lg:h-12 px-4 text-green-500 font-bold uppercase tracking-wider whitespace-nowrap">
                        <?= $escaper->escapeHtml($items['subscribe']) ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <template x-if="displayErrorMessage">
                    <p>
                        <span>
                            <?= $heroicons->exclamationCircleHtml(); ?>
                        </span>
                        <template x-for="errorMessage in errorMessages">
                            <span x-html="errorMessage"></span>
                        </template>
                    </p>
                </template>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="w-full">
            <?= $recaptcha ? $recaptcha->getLegalNoticeHtml(ReCaptcha::RECAPTCHA_FORM_ID_NEWSLETTER) : '' ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

I also have a CMS block with the identifier "blog-subscribe", which contains the JSON data block that the template tries to decode:
{
  "image": "{{media url=&quot;wysiwyg/blog/image.jpg&quot;}}",
  "image-alt": "blog-image alt text",
  "title": "Text",
  "subtitle": "Text",
  "subtitle2": "Text",
  "email-placeholder": "Enter Your Email",
  "subscribe": "Subscribe"
}

After implementing the update, I encountered the following error:
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /data/web/magento2/app/design/frontend/xxxxxx/default/Magento_Newsletter/templates/blog-home-subscribe.phtml on line 24

Here’s the backtrace:
#1 include() called at vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:71
#2 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render()...

The issue seems to stem from this line:
<img class="h-full w-full object-cover"
    src="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($items['image']) ?>"
    alt="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($items['image-alt']) ?>">

I have already tried adding fallback values but it seems to be defaulting to those instead of checking the json that I added on my CMS block. It's set up that way so it's editable via the admin panel.
How can I address this error and make it work? Thank you in advance! Any help would be appreciated.


replace this

<div class="absolute inset-0">
    <img class="h-full w-full object-cover"
        src="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($items['image']) ?>"
        alt="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($items['image-alt']) ?>">
</div>


with this

<?php
if (is_array($items)) {
    $image = isset($items['image']) ? $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($items['image']) : '';
    $imageAlt = isset($items['image-alt']) ? $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($items['image-alt']) : ''; ?>
<div class="absolute inset-0">
    <img class="h-full w-full object-cover"
        src="<?php echo $image ?>"
        alt="<?php echo $imageAlt ?>">
</div>
<?php } ?>

try this and let me know if it works
